# In redmine, how to make "index by title" the start page of wiki

Tags: redmine

In setting of wiki, we can set the start page of the wiki.
uh, my question is how to make the "index by title" to be the start page?
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it in normal way (like set some value in Settings) by default. Maybe you would write a plugin, FYI http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/12275?r=39967

Comment: @FelixYan Thanks, But I don't have the permission to add a plugin to redmine. So, I'm looking for a way to modify the start page by editing project setting. Say, If the `Index by title` is a page in the wiki, I can set this page as start page. The problem is that `Index by title` is not a wiki page, I can not set this page as start page in setting.

Comment: I'm using now Redmine 3.3.1, did anything change? is there any easy way to make "index by title" the default start page for the wiki tab?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following workaround to come up with the desired result:

- Put only the `{{child_pages}}` marco on your Wiki start page
- Put every other Wiki page underneath the start page via the `Rename` feature

After that the start page will basically show you the same entries as the `Index by title` page.

Comment: For me it is not a workaround but a solution, this behavior also may have a benefit of hiding some pages from the main view like personal pages or any pages that shouldn't be on the main view.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to make the "Index by title" page to be start page on Redmine 5.0.x:

1. Open file wiki_controller.rb
2. Find method 'show' and add the code after group 'if params[:version].. end'

> ```
> def show
>   if params[:version] && !User.current.allowed_to?(:view_wiki_edits, @project)
>       deny_access
>       return
>   end
>   if params[:id].nil?
>       redirect_to action: "index"
>       return
>   end
>   ....
> ```

3. Restart Redmine and show the result.